# How to ensure android view is updated properly and completely, before making it visible?

Tags: android

I have a fragment, inside which there is a TextView and some Buttons.

I show the fragment, user clicks on a button, I hide the fragment and show a loading icon, contact server, get a new text and:

```
loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mainContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
http.post("https://domain/service?parameters", 
    new ParameterizedRunnable() {
        text.setText(newTextFromServer)
        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mainContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
});
```

However, when the the main content view becomes visible after service call, I still see the previous text for a very short time, and then the new text is shown.

Why is it so? It seems that the `text.setText` line gets called, but maybe the device is slow and UI is not updated properly before `mainContent.setVisibility` line.

Am I missing some concept about android views and how they get rendered?

Comment: post whole your code plz

Comment: Try using ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener and please be more clear in the explanation, Add a picture of the issue if you can.

Comment: try adding a picture of issue